# How do I define a dimension so that null values in the FK are not ignored when showing all values?

Tags: olap, olap-cube, mondrian

I a modeling an OLAP cube using Modrian Workbench Schema and using Jaspersoft to present it. The cube is built upon a fact table with FKs to dimension tables.
Currently my fact table has nullable foreign keys to the dimensions, which I personally find interesting (and, as far as I know, it is just s styling decision whether to use nullable or not nullable FKs ( https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3512/fact-table-foreign-keys-null ).

The problem is that when selecting ALL States (State is a dimension in my design), I get only the records that have a state, not the records without states (in which the state id is null).

Is Mondrian capable of getting the rows that have not state id information? How can I define that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to go with non-nullable FKs and a *none* / *n/a* / *unknown* etc. member if you want the *ALL* member to refer to all facts.

If you later want to write queries that only consider rows with real dimension values, you can exclude the *none* member again.